# best pythonic way to parse param string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

Receive a string from somewhere and the string is a sequence of params. Params are separated by whitespace. The task is parse the string to a param list, all params are type string.

For example:

```
input : "3 45 5.5 a bc"
output : ["3","45","5.5","a","bc"]
```

Things become little complicated if need to transfer a string include a whitespace, use `"` to quote.

```
input: "3 45 5.5 \"This is a sentence.\" bc"
output: ["3","45","5.5","This is a sentence.","bc"]
```

But what if the sentence happened to include a quote mark? Use the escape character: `\"` -> `"`, `\\` -> `\`

```
input: "3 45 5.5 \"\\\"Yes\\\\No?\\\" it said.\" bc"
output: ['3','45','5.5','"Yes\\NO?" it said.','bc']
```

Does python have an elegant way to do this job?

PS. I don't think regular expressions can work this out.

Comment: [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module using a dialect with whitespace separation?

Comment: Your last input string is a bit off with regard to the backslashes; correcting it will help you get a proper answer quickly.

Comment: "Elegant parser" and "crap data" don't go well side by side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`shlex.split()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("3 45 5.5 a bc")
['3', '45', '5.5', 'a', 'bc']
>>> shlex.split("3 45 5.5 \"This is a sentence.\" bc")
['3', '45', '5.5', 'This is a sentence.', 'bc']
>>> shlex.split("3 45 5.5 \"\\\"Yes\\\\No?\\\" it said.\" bc")
['3', '45', '5.5', '"Yes\\No?" it said.', 'bc']
```

You can create a customizable parser with the [`shlex.shlex` function](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.shlex), then alter it's behaviour by setting its attributes. For example, you can set the `.whitespace` attribute to `', \t\r\n'` to allow commas to delimit words as well. Then simply convert the `shlex` instance back to a list to split the input.